# Readers-Writers problem, with writer preference

Tags: multithreading, semaphore

NO CODE IS NEEDED

I am working on the Readers-Writers problem with writer preference

I am a little confused on how I can give writer preference to some pieces of data.

My naive idea is that I will have a semaphore for each piece of data that is trying to be accessed storing in a heap that orders writers over readers, and then when writer processes try to access the data, the data will yield it to writer(s) first. I feel like this is a bad idea because of all the overhead storage that will be needed for this implementation. 
Do you know a better implementation to this problem?

Thanks, anything helps

Comment: What does "give writer preference" mean? Suppose some thread A already has the data locked, and then some reader thread R tries to acquire the lock, and then some writer W tries for it. Are you saying you want thread W to get the lock ahead of thread R, when thread A releases it? If so, then you need to learn about _[reader-writer locks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock)_. You either need to find one that can be configured to work way that you want, or else you need to learn how to make one that works the way that you want.

Comment: P.S., If I had to make my own, I would not use any container (e.g., no heap). I would use two _[condition variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)#Condition_variables)_, one for the readers, and one for the writers, and I would leave the queueing up to the operating system.

Comment: @Andrew Bury I didn't get your question completely. But if you want to give more priority to a thread you can look at thread scheduling mechanism - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setschedparam.3.html

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking it, there is a common solution to this problem. This is an issue with the Reader-Writer problem and there is lots of documentation over it. Thank you all for the help!